# Why don't `std::basic_string::substr` function have iterator-based overloads

Tags: c++, string

It seems most of the algorithms in the C++ standard library are based on iterators, and yet the ones defined as member functions of `std::basic_string` are index-based. Is there a rationale for not adding the iterator-based overloads?

Comment: I can't give you a rationale for the entire string library but `substr` in particular seems redundant since you can just use the constructor and write `std::string sub(begin, end)`. No reason to make that a member function

Comment: I guess no one ever really saw enough need for them. Just like `std::vector`, also missing the iterator-based functions, the default ones in `<algorithm>` generally work just fine.

Comment: Also `substr` has additional checking for out-of-range indices, and iterators wouldn't be able to do such checks (easily).

Comment: If I'm remembering correctly, `std::string` (or at least what the standardization was based on) predates the STL iterator design altogether. That wouldn't preclude them from being added later of course, just requiring appropriate justification.

Comment: The underlying design principal of the STL (Standard Template Library, adopted in part into C++) is separation of function: containers hold values; iterators describe sequences of values; algorithms operate on sequences. Sometimes a particular algorithm can be implemented more efficiently when you know the structure of a container; that argues for also having a container-specific version of **some** algorithm for **some** containers. It is not an argument for duplicating all of the algorithms inside every container; indeed, that's the opposite of the underlying design principle.

Comment: @chris   It's the other way around.  STL was a library [designed by Alexander Stepanov in the early 90s] that came before the C++ standard library (and its design significantly influenced the design of the standard library).   The STL introduced container types [one of which is the precursor of `std::string`], iterators that (in pairs) represent a range of elements of those containers, and algorithms that work over a range (specified by a pair of iterators) of elements independently of how elements are organised by the container (e.g. contiguous or not).

Comment: Another aspect is that the interface was designed at a time when strings were copy-on-write (COW). I don't recall the exact iterator guarantees from C++03 but if they were just wrappers around pointers (as with `vector`), many operations, even those where you might not expect it (such as `string[index]`), can invalidate them. An index is less likely and more predictably invalidated.

Comment: @Peter, What I meant was that I feel like I saw info about using indices instead of iterators being carried forward from one of the string types that was present before the STL (a pretty popular thing to write when sold the idea of C with classes) rather than the entire basis of the API of `std::string` being invented by Stephanov. However, I've had some trouble digging deeper into the history than the original STL type to actually see the designs of the strings that came before it.